# Java will not use parseInt

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I'm currently trying to read in a formatted file for a maze game I am creating. Whenever I try to compile, however, it states that it cannot find symbols and is pointing to the parseInts inside the try block. I imported `java.lang.Integer`. Does anyone understand why Java is refusing to do so?

```
private Room[][] readRooms(String filepath) throws IOException
{
    int numberOfRooms;
    int numRows;
    int numCols;
    Room[][] grid;

    try
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filepath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String next = null;

        numberOfRooms = parseInt(br.readLine());
        numRows = parseInt(br.readLine());
        numCols = parseInt(br.readLine());

        grid = new Room[numRows][numCols];

        while((next = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (next.equals("***"))
            {

            }
        }

        br.close();
    }

    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("File potentially malformed.");
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

    return grid;
}
```

Note: The string `"***"` is a separator in the text file.

Specific javac output:

```
javac "Maze.java" (in directory: C:\Users\Blaise\Programming\csc300\Maze)
Maze.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
   numberOfRooms = parseInt(br.readLine());
                   ^
  symbol:   method parseInt(String)
  location: class Maze
Maze.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
   numRows = parseInt(br.readLine());
             ^
  symbol:   method parseInt(String)
  location: class Maze
Maze.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
   numCols = parseInt(br.readLine());
             ^
  symbol:   method parseInt(String)
  location: class Maze
3 errors
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: One remark: You do not need it import java.lang-classes since they are always imported implicitly. For mor details, look at @Robby Cornelissen's answer.

Comment: Yes, I was unaware of the fact that java.lang was imported implicitly. If this is the case, why does the Java scanner class need to be explicitly imported?

Comment: Because `Scanner` belongs to the package `java.util`, not `java.lang`. Only `java.lang.*` gets imported implicitly.

Comment: Ah okay. For some reason I thought that Scanner was in the lang package, but I realize that's not the case now that I see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) is a static method declared in the `Integer` class. To invoke it you need to either qualify the method name with the class name as follows:

```
Integer.parseInt(yourString);
```

Or add the following static import statement at the top of your class:

```
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Integer.parseInt(String). It is a static method inside Integer class

Answer (score 0):

You should use the static Integer.parseInt(String) or

```
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `Integer.parseInt(String)`. But if you are trying to import it you should statically import it like this:

```
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import `java.lang.Integer`, because `java.lang` package is always imported. Use static method `Integer.parseInt(str)`